# Feature flag __VUE_PROD_HYDRATION_MISMATCH_DETAILS__ is not explicitly defined. Where do I define it?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Since just upgrading vue.js to version 3.4.4 I now get the following warning in the console of my browser:

Feature flag **VUE_PROD_HYDRATION_MISMATCH_DETAILS** is not explicitly defined. You are running the esm-bundler build of Vue, which expects these compile-time feature flags to be globally injected via the bundler config in order to get better tree-shaking in the production bundle.

So I read that it's some new flag they've introduced.

EDIT:

I'm using a vue.config.js file in my project. Is this where the flag should be added? It currently looks like this:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true
})
```

**My question:** "*Where* do I set this flag"?
I find a lot of info about that I should define this flag but no info on "*where*" I should define it...

Comment: Update `@vitejs/plugin-vue` to v5 or above. You don't need to define it manually if you're not using it.

Comment: @brc-dd I can't seem to find this file. Where would it be located? Or maybe it's not part of my project.

Comment: Ah you're still using webpack. Do it like this - https://vuejs.org/api/compile-time-flags#webpack

Comment: Ah my bad, you're using cli-service. It should be this one - https://vuejs.org/api/compile-time-flags#vue-cli

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using the no longer maintained @vue/cli-service with webpack, it is caused by the fact that the tool does not define the default for this feature flag. It does so for the other two bundler feature flags, and while I created a PR to add this default (as I just hit this myself - https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/pull/7443), I do not expect it to get merged and released as the latest release is from July 2022.

So, you should define it yourself in the webpack configuration using the define plugin.

As they question is update to indicate the use of `vue.config.js`, you can set it like this:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        // Vue CLI is in maintenance mode, and probably won't merge my PR to fix this in their tooling
        // https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/pull/7443
        __VUE_PROD_HYDRATION_MISMATCH_DETAILS__: 'false',
      })
    ],
  },
});
```

See https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack for details on the configuration options.

Comment: Thx, it is probably so that I use the vue/cli-service. I have a vue.config.js file, see my updated post on top. I've tried defining the flag inside of the "defineConfig"-method but that didn't help. Possibly I did it incorrectly. Would you have a suggestion on how to edit my vue.config.js to make it work? Thx!

Comment: This did the trick, also I realized after a while that I also had to rebuild after changing the vue.config.js file because just saving it and reloading the vue-app in the browser was not enough :)

Comment: Same issue, but wondering if there's something I should replace vue/cli-service with if it's no longer maintained?

Comment: @RandyHall From the documentation: "Vue CLI is the official webpack-based toolchain for Vue. It is now in maintenance mode and we recommend starting new projects with Vite unless you rely on specific webpack-only features. Vite will provide superior developer experience in most cases.". See https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling.html.

Comment: @BobvandeVijver thanks! Upgraded my project to Vite, fixed a lot of problems.